# AWS Codebuild fails since buildspec is unable to install python version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

My build fails, unable to install python 3.8, though python 3.8 is a supported runtime.
[image]

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/runtime-versions.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html

My build spec file:

```
 {
    "version": "0.2",
    "phases": {
      "install": {
        "runtime-versions": {
         "python": "3.8"
        }
      },
      "build": {
        "commands": [
          "cd lambda",
          "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt",
          "python -m pip install -r test/requirements.txt",
          "python -m unittest",
        ]
      }
    },
    "artifacts": {
      "files": "**/*"
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
[Container] 2023/07/06 11:54:17 Selecting 'python' runtime version '3.8' based on manual selections...
[Container] 2023/07/06 11:54:17 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/07/06 11:54:17 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '3.8' of python. This build image has the following versions: 3.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Ubuntu Image Standard version 5.0. In Version 6, only Python 3.10 is supported, per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html)

To update it for the existing CodeBuild project, go to the CodeBuild project, click `Edit` button, and choose `Environment`. You will have a button on top saying `Override image`.
Under `Image` select `aws/codebuild/standard:5.0`
Then click on `Update Environment` at the bottom of the page